# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "merit_actions" does not exist LINE 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to sign up, I get this error... but I am able to sign in with the new account.

```html
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "merit_actions" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"merit_actions"'::regclas... ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod, c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation WHERE a.attrelid = '"merit_actions"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum
```

```html
          log(sql, name) do
            ActiveSupport::Dependencies.interlock.permit_concurrent_loads do
              result_as_array @connection.async_exec(sql)
            end
          end
        end
```

I have run reset database and run migrations a few times...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had gems and files that needed to be deleted. :(